# How did I launch this Python script at boot?

Tags: python, boot, script, bash

I have a Python script running at boot, on a Raspberry Pi, and of course I didn't write down how I set it up. Now I need to change it, and I can't for the life of me figure out how it's getting launched. How can I figure this out?

I've searched for methods to launch a script at boot, in the hopes that I will stumble across the right one. For instance, [Run a Program On Your Raspberry Pi At Startup](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) gives several options, and I've gone through each of them, to walk through the setup, and see if I already changed the settings. None of them seem to be what I did.

- `/etc/rc.local` is pretty empty
- It's not in `~/.bashrc` (and I wouldn't want it to be — I want it to run at boot, not when I log in)
- As far as I can tell, it's not in `/etc/init.d/`, but I suppose the launcher script could be named something that I'm not expecting?
- It's not set up as a `systemd` service (Again, as far as I can tell — maybe I named it something weird?)
- There are no `crontab` entries

If I search running processes, I get this:

```
$ ps aux | grep python
root       452  0.0  0.0   1912   396 ?        Ss   12:18   0:00 /bin/sh -c sudo python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
root       453  0.0  0.3   6968  3228 ?        S    12:18   0:00 sudo python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
root       486 11.7  3.7 110344 35912 ?        Sl   12:18   0:04 python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
pi        1205  0.0  0.2   4280  1948 pts/0    S+   12:19   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

`nook_controller.py` is definitely the right Python script, and I'm guessing the `/bin/sh` means it's being run from a shell script… but I am still at a loss of where that shell script lives. Any ideas what my next steps would be to track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just figured it out. Thanks to my colleague Aaron Bendickson for the idea to check the `systemd` configuration file, which sparked the idea to check the `status` command below.

After the steps in the original post, next I tried `systemctl status` and that gave me this:

```
● tikinook3
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Wed 1969-12-31 16:00:03 PST; 48 years 7 months ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─1 /sbin/init
           ├─system.slice
           │ ├─...
           │ ├─cron.service
           │ │ ├─381 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           │ │ ├─402 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
           │ │ ├─452 /bin/sh -c sudo python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
           │ │ ├─453 sudo python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
           │ │ └─486 python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
           ...
```

Ok, so it *is* in cron. But I already looked there.

```
$ crontab -e

# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

The entire thing is commented out. So it's not in this crontab file. Is there another?

YES! — use `sudo`:

```
$ sudo crontab -e

# everything in the above file
# ...
@reboot sudo python /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py
```

*Whew!*

That line should now be:

```
@reboot sudo python3 /home/pi/tikinook/nook_controller.py &
```

I am kind of wondering what that `State: degraded` means in the `systemctl status` results, but that's a question for another time. **EDIT:** I ran `rpi-update` and that `degraded` status resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

One way to discover who launched a particular process is to ask `ps` or `pstree` to print a process tree, revealing process parents:

```
ps -aef
pstree
```

However, this won't help if the parent process disowned your script or died.

Another idea is to find your script by name using `grep`:

```
grep -r "script name" /etc /var /usr/etc /home/pi/.config
```

The above commands should be run as `root` to make sure all processes and files are included in the search.